# Excel T-Test “Set X is better than Set Y by ___%”

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, excel

Coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232615/compute-statistical-significance-with-excel) post, but their question wasn't fully answered.

I understand how the t-test works – if I have two sets of data and want to see if one is better (or worse) than the other, I would say `ttest(setx, sety, 1, 2)` for a type 2, and that would tell me whether or not one set is better/worse than the other. What I don't understand is how to say "Set `X` is better than set `Y` by `__`% with statistical significance." My best guess would be using `ttest(setx, sety*.2, 1, 2)`, and if that still gives me a small enough p-value, then that .2 would turn into "Set `X` is better than set `Y` by 80%." Am I thinking that through correctly?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are probably looking for a confidence interval for the percentage change in mean.

Comment: @Glen_b Not "looking for" a confidence interval, but perhaps should consider using a confidence interval to understand the data. The specific question would require a confidence interval on the difference between the two means rather than the usual pair of confidence intervals for the two means themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to your question. The first is that you want to use a one-tailed t-test so that you are testing setx is "better" (the mean of the population from which setx is a sample is larger). That is easily done with the t.test() function by setting the second parameter to 1 for one tail. Thus t.test(setx,sety,1,2) will perform a t-test for the mean of the population x being larger than the mean of population y, assuming equal variances and the conventional nil-null hypothesis.

It sounds to me like you want to set the null hypothesis for the test to be something other than zero. As excel doesn't allow specification of a value for the null hypothesis you will need to subtract the null hypothesised value from one of your sets of values before implementing the test. If you want to test if setx exceeds sety by 10% then you have to subtract 10% from setx and test whether the adjusted set exceeds sety by 0%, which is the nil-null hypothesis.

(Any reasonable statistical software should require specification of the null hypothesis in my opinion. To not do so is to allow users to remain ignorant of the actual nature of the test being used.)

Comment: Exactly, thanks! So essentially I got them switched - returning to my original example, I should be doing `ttest((setX*.2), setY, 1, 2)` and if that is still < 0.05 (and I already know mean(setX) is better/greater than mean(setY)), then setX is better than setY by 80%, with a 95% confidence level.

Comment: @Michael I would have thought that you would have wanted to add the percent to y rather than subtracting the percent from x.  Doesn't x is 10 percent more than y mean $x-y= .1y$?

Comment: @jsk It makes no difference whether you add to one or subtract from the other.

Comment: @user45156 I don't think that you should use a multiple for the adjustment of the null hypothesis as conventionally the test would be dealing with an arithmetic difference between the groups. Subtract a fixed value from all of the data in setx.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  What still seems not to be clear is how you pick this fixed value.  What does it mean to subtract 10%? 10% of what?

Comment: @jsk You have to subtract the value that you want to use as the null hypothesis. If your null is that the two populations differ by a value equal to 10% of the mean of one or other of them then you subtract that amount. If you multiply by a fixed fraction then it is as if you have a different null for each observation, which is not generally correct.

Comment: @MichaelLew Since you don't know the mean of either of the populations, then how do you subtract a value equal to 10% of one of them?

Comment: @jsk Setting the null hypothesis requires knowing what the value the parameter takes as the null hypothesis. You can set it to any value that you desire. The original question specifies it as ___%

Comment: @MichaelLew Couldn't you actually just calculate 10% of the sample mean of sety, then subtact this value from setx?

Comment: @jsk Yes, if that is your desired null hypothesis then yes. Of course.

Comment: @MichaelLew There's something that doesn't seem quite right about doing this.... you're not subtracting a constant.  Are you sure that the estimate of the standard error will be correct?  The calculation you are performing has $(\bar{X}-1.1\bar{Y})$ in the numerator of the t-statistic, but will have an estimated standard error of $\sqrt{S_X^2/n_1 + S_Y^2/n_2}$ in the denominator, which doesn't seem to be correct...

Comment: @jsk Perhaps you should ask a question instead of extending this comment thread. Your question seem to me to be based on a mis- or non-reading of comments further up the thread. Dividing the values by a constant is not the same as subtracting the null hypothesised value of the parameter, as your calculation of the standard error shows. What is your question?

Comment: @MichaelLew Here's my understanding.  You seem to be telling him to set up a null hypothesis of the form $H_0: \mu_x-\mu_y=c$ vs $H_A: \mu_x-\mu_y>c$ where the constant $c$ is somehow supposed to correspond to a % difference in the two means.  I don't understand how the constant $c$ can simultaneously correspond to an absolute difference in the two means as well as a % difference.  If I reject this null hypothesis, it seems to me that the only thing I can conclude is that the absolute difference in means is greater than $c$.  Thanks for your help in clarifying my misunderstanding.

Comment: @jsk Estimate the unknown mean of the population using the sample mean. Calculate 10% of that. Subtract that value from the observations of one group. Do the t-test.

Comment: @MichaelLew You do realize that your approach is equivalent to having $\bar{X} - .1\bar{Y} - \bar{Y} = \bar{X} - 1.1\bar{Y}$, in the numerator of your t-statistic, right?

Comment: @jsk Please write out your own answer to the original question if mine is in some manner deficient.

Comment: @MichaelLew Surely you are aware that $var( \bar{X} - 1.1\bar{Y})\neq \sigma_x^2/n_x + \sigma_y^2/n_y$.  I'm sure you must also be aware that if you take a column of data, $Y$, and define a new column to be $Z = Y+.1\bar{Y}$, then $S_Z^2$ = $S_Y^2$ where $S_Z^2$ is the sample variance of $Z$ and $S_Y^2$ is the sample variance of Y.  Now do you see the problem with your answer?  What do you think will be the estimated standard error in the denominator of the t-statistic as estimated by excel?  I'll give you a hint. It's in a previous comment that you rudely dismissed as my own misunderstanding.

Comment: I made some edits to the above comments. Please, note that we do have public or private chat rooms for extended discussion (comments are 2nd class citizen on SE). At this point, @jsk, you could write your own answer if you have time and inclination.